# Frequency of planet masses in any given star system?

Tags: planet, distribution-function

This question is a follow-up to [the expected distribution of planet masses in a given system.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/45486/31410) I am wondering, what is the distribution of various planet masses in any given system?

I am expecting a bimodal distribution with peaks at $5M_\oplus$ and somewhere near the $1-3 M_J$ range, with an intermediate minimum near the super-Neptune mass range. Is this an accurate description of said distribution or am I completely off?

Comment: Potentially helpful: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/808/1/71

Comment: I think I might have partially answered this question in my answer in the predecessor one - though not quite a satisfying one for this, I fear - though the plot might be the answer here (head to exoplanet.eu and plot mass over whatever you like). Yet for *one* given system it might look different - statistics for multiple ones are scarce still. Only the total enesemble is reasonably-well understood